# Spark not utilizing all the core while running LinearRegressionwithSGD

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib

I am running Spark on my local machine (16G,8 cpu cores). I was trying to train linear regression model on dataset of size 300MB. I checked the cpu statistics and also the programs running, it just executes one thread.
The documentation says they have implemented distributed version of SGD.
http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/mllib-linear-methods.html#implementation-developer

```py
from pyspark.mllib.regression import LabeledPoint, LinearRegressionWithSGD, LinearRegressionModel
from pyspark import SparkContext


def parsePoint(line):
  values = [float(x) for x in line.replace(',', ' ').split(' ')]
  return LabeledPoint(values[0], values[1:])

sc = SparkContext("local", "Linear Reg Simple")
data = sc.textFile("/home/guptap/Dropbox/spark_opt/test.txt")
data.cache()
parsedData = data.map(parsePoint)


model = LinearRegressionWithSGD.train(parsedData)

valuesAndPreds = parsedData.map(lambda p: (p.label,model.predict(p.features)))
MSE = valuesAndPreds.map(lambda (v, p): (v - p)**2).reduce(lambda x, y: x + y) / valuesAndPreds.count()
print("Mean Squared Error = " + str(MSE))


model.save(sc, "myModelPath")
sameModel = LinearRegressionModel.load(sc, "myModelPath")
```

Comment: How are you submitting your script?

Comment: @eliashah I am using pyspark-submit --master local[*] script_name.py

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what you want to do is explicitly state the number of cores to use with the local context. As you can see from the comments [here](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/SparkConf.scala#L77), `"local"` (which is what you're doing) instantiates a context on one thread whereas `"local[4]"` will run with 4 cores. I believe you can also use `"local[*]"` to run on all cores on your system.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I was not checking the threads but was monitoring processes which got me confused.